# Can contextual bandit rewards be changed over time?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit, reward

I am working on implementing a contextual bandit with Vowpal Wabbit for dynamic pricing where arms represent price margins. The cost/reward is determined by taking price – expected cost. Cost is not known initially so it is a prediction and has the potential to change. My question is, if your cost/reward can change over time can you update the cost/reward to reflect the realized cost and retrain the model?

Below is an example with a training set with 1 feature (user) and a test set. The cost was based on the expected net revenue. The model is trained and used to predict which action to take for the customers in the test set.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import numpy as np
from vowpalwabbit import pyvw

train_data = [{'action': 1, 'cost': -150, 'probability': 0.4, 'user': 'a'},
              {'action': 3, 'cost': 0, 'probability': 0.2, 'user': 'b'},
              {'action': 4, 'cost': -250, 'probability': 0.5, 'user': 'c'},
              {'action': 2, 'cost': 0, 'probability': 0.3, 'user': 'a'},
              {'action': 3, 'cost': 0, 'probability': 0.7, 'user': 'a'}]

train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)

# Add index to data frame
train_df['index'] = range(1, len(train_df) + 1)
train_df = train_df.set_index("index")

# Test data
test_data = [{'user': 'b'},
            {'user': 'a'},
            {'user': 'b'},
            {'user': 'c'}]

test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)

# Add index to data frame
test_df['index'] = range(1, len(test_df) + 1)
test_df = test_df.set_index("index")

# Create python model and learn from each trained example
vw = pyvw.vw("--cb 4")

for i in train_df.index:
  action = train_df.loc[i, "action"]
  cost = train_df.loc[i, "cost"]
  probability = train_df.loc[i, "probability"]
  user = train_df.loc[i, "user"]

  # Construct the example in the required vw format.
  learn_example = str(action) + ":" + str(cost) + ":" + str(probability) + " | " + str(user) 

  # Here we do the actual learning.
  vw.learn(learn_example)
  
# Predict actions
for j in test_df.index:
  user = test_df.loc[j, "user"]

  test_example = "| " + str(user)

  choice = vw.predict(test_example)
  print(j, choice)
```

However, after a week we received new information and the cost was higher than expected for index 0 in the training set and lower than expected at index 2. Can this new information be used to retrain the model and predict actions?

```
## Reward/cost changed after 1 week once cost was realized
train_data = [{'action': 1, 'cost': 200, 'probability': 0.4, 'user': 'a'}, # Lost money
              {'action': 3, 'cost': 0, 'probability': 0.2, 'user': 'b'},
              {'action': 4, 'cost': -350, 'probability': 0.5, 'user': 'c'}, # Made more than exp.
              {'action': 2, 'cost': 0, 'probability': 0.3, 'user': 'a'},
              {'action': 3, 'cost': 0, 'probability': 0.7, 'user': 'a'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I don't see why changing the reward over time would be a problem. This is certainly how the real world works too. Actions may be less or more appropriate in a changing world. Contextual bandits work well in a non-stationary environment, so it should be fine.

One thing to note though is that if your environment is non-stationary you probably want to provide the `--power_t` option as `0`. By default, VW's learning rate decays over time (`t`) as if your problem stationary you would want to converge on a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Would that also apply if I am using --cb_explore_adf? I was using --cb 4 in this example for simplicity. Also, is there somewhere that lists what the default hyperparameters are set to? I am having a hard time finding that information.

Comment: Yep, same for ADF. You can look [here](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/VW-arguments-JSON-format) for default option values. Some things aren't written in such a way that their default is in that list at which point it is looking through the code which is not great, sorry about that. I'll do a pass now to see what I can make be exposed in that wiki page.